# Using nested if statements ( Help )

Tags: if-statement, nested, statements

**Hi, I would appreciate helping me with this question:**

A company awards its customers a discount based on their value of purchases and number of children in the family according to the following specifications:

• If the value of purchases is $5000 or more, and number of children in the family is more than 7, the discount is 30% of the value of purchases.

• If the value of purchases is $5000 or more and number of children in the family is more than 4, the discount is 22% of the value of purchases.

• If the value of purchases is less than or equal to $2500, the discount is 10% 

For example, a customer pays $5000, and gets 30% of 5000, i.e.

(30/100) * 5000 = $1500.

1. Using nested if statements, write a JavaScript code which will work according to the following specifications:

•   Read the amount of purchases for a customer and number of children in the family

•   Calculate the discount for that customer according to the above description

•   Calculate and then print the final price of the value of purchases after the discount

Comment: Perhaps you can show what part of your assignment or homework that you've tried already.

Comment: This is not a place where you send your homework and someone writes the code for you.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Or do you just want people to solve your assignment for you^^

Comment: Please edit your post, include the code you've written, and explain the specific problems you've encountered.  We're not going to do your homework for you, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var purchaseValue = 7000;
var children = 10;
var discount = 0;
if(purchaseValue >= 5000){
  if(children > 4){
    discount = 22;
  }
  else if(children > 7){
    discount = 30;
  }
}
else if(purchaseValue <= 2500){
   discount = 10;
}
var amount = (discount/100) * purchaseValue;
```

Comment: should delete this.  Why give someone who hasn't tried the easy way out?

Comment: if it helps someone learn, then it has value

Comment: Yeah, but lets be honest, giving people answers who don't try themselves has never been an effective way to help someone 'learn'

Comment: It's not going to help him learn anything other than to paste his next piece of homework on here without trying.  If he'd actually made an effort and provided some code examples then fine.  Just pasting it is taking the piss.